# Putting Commas in a Decimal

Tags: c#

IF i have the following:

```
MyString.ValueType = typeof(System.Decimal);
```

how can i make this have an output of decimals with commas?  In other words, instead of seeing 1234.5, i'd like to see 1,234.5

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
String output = MyString.ValueType.ToString("N");
```

The "N" format specifier will put in the thousands separators (,).  For details, see [Decimal.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx).

Edit:

The above will use your current culture settings, so the thousands separators will depend on the current locale.  However, if you want it to always use comma, and period for the decimal separator, you can do:

```
String output = MyString.ValueType.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That will force it to use the InvariantCulture, which uses comma for thousands and period for decimal separation, which means you'll always see "1,234.5".

Comment: The thousands separator that is actually used will be culture dependent.

Comment: Yes. That's why I called it "thousands separators" instead of just saying comma - but this is typically the "correct" approach.  I'll edit to clarify...

Comment: Yes it does, now I don't walk away with the impression that "N" will always use (,) as thousands separator. +1 to the edit...